# Laravel Resource Controller Dynamic Total Results Displayed

Tags: laravel, controller, resources

here's my 
Resource Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Employees;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\EmployeesResource;

class EmployeesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user = new EmployeesResource(Employees::paginate(5));
        return $user;
    }

}
```

As you can see, I'm only fetching 5 results per request.
How can I pass a parameter to a resource route to make the total results dynamic. 
Making the link : `http://xdomain.com/employees?page=1&per_page=10`,doesn't seem to work.

Comment: My guess would be that if you wanted to make `per_page` dynamic, you would have to paginate based on the query parameter value. At the moment you are statically limiting to 5 per page.

Answer (score 0):

Use your `?per_page` querystring parameter.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return new EmployeesResource(
        Employees::paginate($request->query('per_page'))
    );
}
```